# Congruent Partitions of Regular Polygons

Tags: geometry

For given $n \ge 3$, what are the values of a positive integer $c$ such that an $n$-sided regular polygon can be partitioned into $c$ congruent parts?

For $n=4$,  $c\in\mathbb{N}$. Just cut congruent strips of width $a/c$, and length $a$ for the given square of side $a$.

For $n=3$, $c = 3, 4, 6, 8,\ldots$ (multiples of $3$ and $4$, but not sure about others yet)

Some insight over $n$ in general (and even $n=3$ in particular) would be highly appreciated. :)

As per now, I am considering the 'parts' as connected, but if someone has disconnected congruency ideas, they are most welcome (but note disconnected parts shouldn't be transformed, i.e. rotated, dilated, etc)!

Answer (score 1):

For any $n$ you can get $n$ pieces using a radial decomposition. Then you can get 2n by bisecting the resulting isosceles triangles.

For $n=3$ you can get any square by slicing an equilateral triangle into smaller equilateral triangles with $k$ lines equally spaced parallel to the edges. That will produce
$$
1 + 3 + 5 + \cdots + (2k+1) = (k+1)^2
$$
smaller triangles. Just draw larger and larger equilateral triangles on this grid to see the dissections:

[image]

In fact that construction works for any triangle, not just an equilateral triangle, so whenever you have a dissection into $t$ congruent triangles you can construct a dissection into $t(k+1)^2$ congruent triangles.

Comment: @AmitBendkhale See the image in my edit.

Comment: Great, nice intuition! Tnx for expanding the set for n=3 :) So, now the question is are there other values of c , other than the ones obtained above?...like can we partition equilateral triangle into 5 congruent parts?